# Using shared datasets across different projects

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008

facts: Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services

I have a solution that consists of several projects. This is because of the inability to create nested deploy folders.

So my solution looks like this:

- Students -> reports deploy to Students
- StudentsGraduated -> reports    deploy to Students/Graduated
- StudentsGraduatedWithHonours _> reports    deploy to Students/Graduated/WithHonours
- StudentsBlueEyes -> reports    deploy to Students/BlueEyes
- StudentsGreenEyes -> reports deploy to    Students/GreenEyes

All reports should use one dataset, with proper filters.

So I set up deployment so that each project deploys its datasets in /Student/DataSets. I made sure that each project has a identical dataset so that, when deployed, they all use the same dataset.

But apparently this does not work. Only the last deployed report can use the dataset :(

- If I put all reports using a dataset in the same project it works but I have manually to move all reports to their proper locations.
- Setting up all projects to deploy their reports in their own DataSet folder works too, but then I have a lot of identical DataSets lying around, which kinda beats the purpose.
- After deployment manually resetting the dataset using the reportmanager works but is rather a tedious exercise when you have like 7 datasets on avg in each report and 19 reports......

Is this  known phenomenon? Is it possible to have reports from different projects use the same dataset? If so, how?

I really would like to know your thoughts on this......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I was doing it should [according to this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/71e98344-8b35-4ac9-abbf-d2058c2c820d?prof=required) be the right way.
So I redid it, following the steps outlined  in [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/71e98344-8b35-4ac9-abbf-d2058c2c820d?prof=required) by [Charlie Liao](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/charlie%20liao/?ws=usercard-mini):
1. create the datasets in one of your projects
2. ADD these as existing items to another project
3. Set Overwrite Datasets to TRUE.

I think it was step 2 where I went wrong. I just recreated the dataset in each project, I did not add them. I deleted all datasets in all projects (but the first) and then readded all datasets to all projects as existing items, set Overwrite to True and deployed.

MAGIC!!

:)